# Removing keys from dictionary by specifying only a part of key

Tags: python, dictionary

Python 3:

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
d={aaa0:'Hello',aaa1:'how',bbb0:'are',bb1:'you'}
```

Now how can I remove all the keys that contain 'a' in keys? I know how to remove keys by specifying each key and then deleting it.

I want to know if there is any "pythonic" way to remove keys by specifying just the part of the key.
Like:

```
if d['contains a'] del[key]
```

something like that.

Expected Output:

```
d={bbb0:'are',bb1:'you'}
```

Comment: `d` is not valid Python. Show us your real code.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @LutzHorn Python 3

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary comprehension works for this

```
d = {'aaa0':'Hello','aaa1':'how','bbb0':'are','bb1':'you'}

e = {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if 'a' not in k}

{'bb1': 'you', 'bbb0': 'are'}
```

Edit: This is in Python 2.7

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`, at least not in Python 3.

Comment: you're probably in Python 3, OP did not specify which version he is using so I will edit with a disclaimer

Comment: it does, but in Python 2 `items` builds a list of tuples and returns that so it can consume a lot of memory if its a large dictionary

Comment: But who is using Python 2 in 2018? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to create a new dict:

```
>>> d = {"a1": "A0", "a1": "A1", "b1": "B1", "b2": "B2"}
>>> e = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if not "a" in k}
>>> e
{'b2': 'B2', 'b1': 'B1'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to remove items from your dict:

```
d = {"aaa0":'Hello',"aaa1":'how',"bbb0":'are',"bb1":'you'}
for k in list(d):
  if 'a' in k:
    del d[k]
print(d)
```

This will modify the current dict by iterating over its keys, and not create a new one like other answers have suggested.

***Edit:*** This code will work in *both* Python 2 and 3 without modification.